# Is the 'foreach' loop here behaving in parallel or squential?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to javascript and I am trying to debug this piece of code, I was given in my class

```
fs.readdir('.', function(err, filenames) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Number of Directory Entries:", filenames.length)
  filenames.forEach(function (name) {
    fs.stat(name, function(err, stats) {
      if (err) throw err;
      total += stats.size;
    });
  });
});
```

I would like to know what is the program flow of the for-each will be? Will be in parallel or sequential? The instructor said that it is parallel,  however from what I have read on the web,it seems it is sequential.

Is there anyway, I can tell by debugging like in java?

Comment: `forEach` itself is not async so it is normally sequential. However `fs.stat` is async which will make it parallel. To be VERY percise, `forEach` runs sequentially to call `fs.stat` but `fs.stat` returns immediately and does nothing. AFTER the `forEach` has completed all the `fs.stat` calls will run in parallel and be processed sequentially depending on which of them complete first.

Comment: @slebetman - You should make that an answer.

Comment: the for loop is sequential but the fs.stat is in parallel.  This is different from java in the sense that java is multithreaded and javascript is single threaded.  It is an event based language.

Comment: can you please tell me which ide are you using?

Comment: Anyone who want free points feel free to make my comment an answer :)

Comment: @Ahmer I am running it console, which IDE should I use?

Comment: jetbrain webstorm it have a great feature of debugging  you just need to configure the server file and node Interperator then it will give you two type of running function once is normal second one is debugging mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little bit of both.  **The `.forEach()` loop is sequential (synchronous)**, but **the `fs.stat()` call inside of it is asynchronous** so all the `fs.stat()` calls will be in-flight at the same time (e.g. in parallel).  So, this is what that means in a little more detail:

The `.forEach()` call will run immediately, starting all your `fs.stat()` calls.  But, because they are async, they will just get started in the `.forEach()` loop.  Then, sometime AFTER the `.forEach()` loop finishes when the system has finished each disk action, the `fs.stat()` callbacks will all get called.

The only place that you will actually know what the `total` variable ends up with is in the last `fs.stat()` callback that gets called.  The way you've written your code, you can't reliably know when that is because the `fs.stat()` calls are not guaranteed to finish in any particular order.

You could see what the grand total is by keep track of when the last callback is called by using a counter with something like this:

```
fs.readdir('.', function(err, filenames) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Number of Directory Entries:", filenames.length)
  var doneCnt = 0;
  filenames.forEach(function (name) {
    fs.stat(name, function(err, stats) {
      ++doneCnt;
      if (err) throw err;
      total += stats.size;
      if (doneCnt === filesnames.length) {
          // all callbacks have completed now
          console.log("Final total is: " + total);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And, FYI it does no good to do `throw err` inside the `fs.stat()` or `fs.readdir()` callback.  That exception just goes back into the asynchronous `fs.readdir()` or `fs.stat()` infrastructure and does not go anywhere that you can catch it or will even see it.  You will likely need better error handling than what you have (this is where promises are so much better at handling async errors).

---

If you wanted to understand the sequencing of things, you could put some `console.log()` statements in and watch what order they get executed:

```
fs.readdir('.', function(err, filenames) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Number of Directory Entries:", filenames.length)
  var doneCnt = 0;
  filenames.forEach(function (name, index) {
    console.log("forEach: " + index);
    fs.stat(name, function(err, stats) {
      console.log("fsStat: " + index);
      ++doneCnt;
      if (err) throw err;
      total += stats.size;
      if (doneCnt === filesnames.length) {
          // all callbacks have completed now
          console.log("Final total is: " + total);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

If there were 5 filenames, what you would see in the log would be something like this:

```
forEach: 0
forEach: 1
forEach: 2
forEach: 3
forEach: 4
fsStat: 0
fsStat: 1
fsStat: 2
fsStat: 3
fsStat: 4
Final total is: 57684
```

In fact, the fsStat callbacks are not guaranteed to get called in any particular order among themselves, but they are guaranteed to be AFTER all the forEach log statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a master in JS, I think the basic principle to run parallels function is iterate some call of a  asynchronous function. (Ajax for example) and I don't think that's the case, right? So, it's sequencial.